# Azure Kubernetes - Setup Istio with both Ingress & Egress Gateway?

Tags: kubernetes, istio, azure-aks

I am planning to install Istion on my AKS Cluster using the following configuration, what are all the components this would install? would it install both the Ingress & Egress Gateways?

```
istioctl operator init

kubectl create ns istio-system

cat << EOF | kubectl apply -f -
apiVersion: install.istio.io/v1alpha1
kind: IstioOperator
metadata:
  namespace: istio-system
  name: istio-control-plane
spec:
  # Use the default profile as the base
  # More details at: https://istio.io/docs/setup/additional-setup/config-profiles/
  profile: default
  # Enable the addons that we will want to use
  addonComponents:
    grafana:
      enabled: true
    prometheus:
      enabled: true
    tracing:
      enabled: true
    kiali:
      enabled: true
  values:
    global:
      # Ensure that the Istio pods are only scheduled to run on Linux nodes
      defaultNodeSelector:
        beta.kubernetes.io/os: linux
    kiali:
      dashboard:
        auth:
          strategy: anonymous
EOF
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used the following configuration to setup both the Ingress & Egress Gateways.

```
cat << EOF | kubectl apply -f -
apiVersion: install.istio.io/v1alpha1
kind: IstioOperator
metadata:
  namespace: istio-system
  name: istio-control-plane
spec:
  # Use the default profile as the base
  # More details at: https://istio.io/docs/setup/additional-setup/config-profiles/
  profile: default
  # Enable the addons that we will want to use
  addonComponents:
    grafana:
      enabled: true
    prometheus:
      enabled: true
    tracing:
      enabled: true
    kiali:
      enabled: true
  values:
    global:
      # Ensure that the Istio pods are only scheduled to run on Linux nodes
      defaultNodeSelector:
        beta.kubernetes.io/os: linux
    kiali:
      dashboard:
        auth:
          strategy: anonymous
  components:
    egressGateways:
    - name: istio-egressgateway
      enabled: true
EOF
```

Answer (score 1):

The istio operator manifest in your question will not install egress gateway. It is based on default profile which according to istio documentation can be inspected by using [`istioctl profile dump`](https://istio.io/latest/docs/setup/install/istioctl/#display-the-configuration-of-a-profile):

> **default**: enables components according to the default settings of the [`IstioOperator`  API](https://istio.io/latest/docs/reference/config/istio.operator.v1alpha1/). This profile is recommended for production deployments and for primary clusters in a [multicluster mesh](https://istio.io/latest/docs/ops/deployment/deployment-models/#multiple-clusters). You can display the default setting by running the command `istioctl profile dump`.

In order to install egress gateway using `IstioOperator` follow these steps from istio [documentation](https://istio.io/latest/docs/setup/install/istioctl/#configure-gateways):

> #### Configure gateways
>
> Gateways are a special type of component, since multiple ingress and egress gateways can be defined. In the  [`IstioOperator`  API](https://istio.io/latest/docs/reference/config/istio.operator.v1alpha1/), gateways are defined as a list type. **The  `default`  profile installs one ingress gateway, called  `istio-ingressgateway`.** You can inspect the default values for this gateway:
>
> ```
> istioctl profile dump --config-path components.ingressGateways
> istioctl profile dump --config-path values.gateways.istio-ingressgateway
> ```
>
> These commands show both the  `IstioOperator`  and Helm settings for the gateway, which are used together to define the generated gateway resources. The built-in gateways can be customized just like any other component.
>
> *From 1.7 onward, the gateway name must always be specified when overlaying. Not specifying any name no longer defaults to  `istio-ingressgateway`  or  `istio-egressgateway`.*
>
> A new user gateway can be created by adding a new list entry:
>
> ```
> apiVersion: install.istio.io/v1alpha1
> kind: IstioOperator
> spec:
>   components:
>     ingressGateways:
>       - name: istio-ingressgateway
>         enabled: true
>       - namespace: user-ingressgateway-ns
>         name: ilb-gateway
>         enabled: true
>         k8s:
>           resources:
>             requests:
>               cpu: 200m
>           serviceAnnotations:
>             cloud.google.com/load-balancer-type: "internal"
>           service:
>             ports:
>             - port: 8060
>               targetPort: 8060
>               name: tcp-citadel-grpc-tls
>             - port: 5353
>               name: tcp-dns
> ```
>
> Note that Helm values (`spec.values.gateways.istio-ingressgateway/egressgateway`) are shared by all ingress/egress gateways. If these must be customized per gateway, it is recommended to use a separate IstioOperator CR to generate a manifest for the user gateways, separate from the main Istio installation:
>
> ```
> apiVersion: install.istio.io/v1alpha1
> kind: IstioOperator
> spec:
>   profile: empty
>   components:
>     ingressGateways:
>       - name: ilb-gateway
>         namespace: user-ingressgateway-ns
>         enabled: true
>         # Copy settings from istio-ingressgateway as needed.
>   values:
>     gateways:
>       istio-ingressgateway:
>         debug: error
> ```

More information about installing istio on AKS can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/servicemesh-istio-install?pivots=client-operating-system-linux).

Comment: Thank you, I was able to figure it out.